# How to access to value in array in template html in a HTML tag

Tags: arrays, angular, indexing

i have this in my html template :

```
<button nbButton hero status="success" style="float:right" [disabled]="boolUpdate[0]">UPDATE</button>
```

`boolUpdate` is an array of boolean in my component.
How to access to the first element (index 0) of the `boolUpdate` variable
in this place `[disabled]=` ?

Comment: So what have you try so far ? Do you have any error ?

Comment: `CenterPricesComponent.html:26 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: the error indicates that boolUpdate has no value

Comment: I think you should console.log the boolUpdate to see if there any data

Comment: Your `boolUpdate` variable should be global, not declared in a function inside your component.ts.

Comment: since your `boolUpdate[]` array is populated initally it is empty so there is no  item at `boolUpdate[0]` your best way to use it is use it in *ngFor   `<div *ngFor="let item of boolUpdate"><button nbButton hero status="success" style="float:right" [disabled]="boolUpdate[item]">UPDATE</button></div>`

Comment: @Fealo or you could use just  `[disabled]="boolUpdate ? boolUpdate[0] : true"`